# Besides TheDAO - what are some examples of where Ether has been hacked, stolen or lost?

Tags: ether, security, attacks

Besides TheDAO - what are some examples of where Ether has been hacked, stolen or lost ?

Comment: Was auto-flagged as low-quality.  Converted to wiki: Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

Answer (score 5):

After the DAO hack, some people created a list together [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4omdlf/to_kickstart_the_building_safer_smart_contracts/).
You can also check [Vitalik's blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/19/thinking-smart-contract-security/) about it:

```
The DAO (obviously)
The “payout index without the underscore” ponzi (“FirePonzi”)
The casino with a public RNG seed
Governmental (1100 ETH stuck because payout exceeds gas limit)
5800 ETH swiped (by whitehats) from an ETH-backed ERC20 token
The King of the Ether game
Rubixi : Fees stolen because the constructor function had an incorrect name, allowing anyone to become the owner
Rock paper scissors trivially cheatable because the first to move shows their hand
Various instances of funds lost because a recipient contained a fallback function that consumed more than 2300 gas, causing sends to them to fail.
Various instances of call stack limit exceptions.
```

We can categorize the list by categories of bugs:

```
Variable/function naming mixups: FirePonzi, Rubixi
Public data that should not have been public: the public RNG seed casino, cheatable RPS
Re-entrancy (A calling B calling A): the DAO, Maker’s ETH-backed token
Sends failing due to 2300 gas limit: King of the Ether
Arrays/loops and gas limits: Governmental
Much more subtle game-theoretic weaknesses where at the limit people even debate whether or not they’re bugs: the DAO
```

Comment: Question about `governmental` - how it was unstuck? https://imgur.com/a/KTHp7wW • https://etherscan.io/address/0xf45717552f12ef7cb65e95476f217ea008167ae3#code • https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0d80d67202bd9cb6773df8dd2020e7190a1b0793e8ec4fc105257e8128f0506b ?

Answer (score 2):

There was a geth security risk that led to [at least 7000 ETH being stolen](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4jj92n/7218eth_hacked_geth_and_mists_ipc_security_risk/).

EthereumJS had a bug that [occasionally caused it to derive the wrong address from a given private key](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/47nkoi/psa_check_your_ethaddressorg_wallets_and_any/). It would happen with a probability of 1/128. This may have resulted in a lot of lost ETH.

The exchange GateCoin was hacked, [resulting in the theft of 185,000 ETH.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4rhtxj/hacked_gatecoin_raises_500k_to_reimburse_eth/)